# How to get the last iteration in cursor prematurely?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, cursor

How to get the last iteration in cursor prematurely to compare it with value and break if it meets the condition .

```
OPEN lcr_trans   
    FETCH NEXT FROM lcr_trans INTO @trans_time , @machine_id , @trans_camp_code;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN
    IF(cast(@shift_start_time as time)<>'00:00:00.0000000'  AND (cast(@shift_end_time as time)<>'00:00:00.0000000' )  )
    BEGIN

      SELECT  TOP 1 @CompareWeekend= transtime_out from overtime where emp_num = @emp_num and trans_date = @previous_date;

      IF(@CompareWeekend  = @trans_time)
        BEGIN
            BREAK;
        END
    END
    -- The Cursor --
    --   ----     --
        FETCH NEXT FROM lcr_trans INTO @trans_time , @machine_id , @trans_camp_code;
    END 
    close lcr_trans;
    DEALLOCATE lcr_trans;
```

I want the last `@trans_time` in the iteration to compare with my variable .`@CompareWeekend`

Comment: Can't you check the condition outside the cursor btw? Saves you some time and I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last row in the cursor with the `LAST` keyword ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx)):

```
FETCH LAST FROM lcr_trans INTO @trans_time , @machine_i , @trans_camp_code;
```

Comment: How to use it in my context ? i just want to use it in the if condition not to confuse the loop

Comment: If you declare the `CURSOR` with the `SCROLL` option you can first check the condition for the last record and then get back to the `FIRST` record. [Check the remarks here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: Could you rewrite my cursor with your part please

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
declare @last_trans_time datetime, @last_machine_i varchar(max), @last_trans_camp_code varchar(max);
    OPEN lcr_trans   
        FETCH LAST FROM lcr_trans INTO @last_trans_time , @last_machine_i , @last_trans_camp_code;

        FETCH NEXT FROM lcr_trans INTO @trans_time , @machine_id , @trans_camp_code;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
        BEGIN
           IF(cast(@shift_start_time as time)<>'00:00:00.0000000'  AND (cast(@shift_end_time as time)<>'00:00:00.0000000' )  )
           BEGIN

             SELECT  TOP 1 @CompareWeekend= transtime_out from overtime where emp_num = @emp_num and trans_date = @previous_date;

             IF(@CompareWeekend  = @trans_time)
             BEGIN
               BREAK;
             END
           END
           FETCH NEXT FROM lcr_trans INTO @trans_time , @machine_id , @trans_camp_code;
        END 
   CLOSE lcr_trans;
   DEALLOCATE lcr_trans;
```

you can read more about cursors here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx